# Long Running Query - Recommendations to improve performance in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

```
SELECT
    A.load,
    A.sender,
    A.latlong,
    COUNT(distinct B.load) as load_count,
    COUNT(distinct B.sender) as sender_count
FROM TABLE_A A
JOIN TABLE_B B ON 
    A.sender <> B.sender AND
    (
        A.latlong = B.latlong 
        or
        ( 
            lower(A.address_line1) = lower(B.address_line1)
            and lower(A.city) = lower(B.city)
            and lower(A.state) = lower(B.state)
            and lower(A.country) = lower(B.country)
        )
    )
GROUP BY A.load, A.sender, A.latlong ;
```

I am trying to run a query as above sample, which runs for more time (approx 2 hrs) which is not at all expected. I am trying to split the query and do `UNION` but the result sets are not matching.

Can you please help with options to improve this query performance or alternative ways to achieve this in AWS?

Approximately 1.5 million records

Comment: . . Please explain what the query is supposed to be doing.  Also provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What are the DISTKEY and SORTKEY for the tables?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing the to lower function and sanitizing the data to be lower case

```
select
 A.load, A.sender, A.latlong,
 count(distinct B.load) as load_count,
 count(distinct B.sender) as sender_count
 from 
 TABLE_A A
 join 
 TABLE_B B
 on 
 A.sender <> B.sender and
 (
 A.latlong = B.latlong 
 or
 ( 
  A.address_line1 =  B.address_line1
  and A.city) =  B.city)
  and A.state) =  B.state)
  and A.country) =  B.country)
 ))
 group by 
 A.load, A.sender, A.latlong ;
```

Comment: please explain why you think this might help?

Comment: The reason I suggested removing the function call and sanitizing the data is function calls will slow down the code function and are most likely the root cause of his performance issue. Data sanitation is a good standard practice just like when you put user responses into a database.